# Changing UIWebView default color to UIImage

Tags: uiwebview

Is it possible to place an image in the UIWebView background instead of that gray default color. If yes then how?

Answer (score 2):

Did it by myself.

```
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:backgroundImage]];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your viewDidLoad please Add this code for loading image at startup

```
[webView setOpaque:NO];
  webView.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"night.jpg"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:imagePath]];
```